# Can I use PC3L-12800U memory modules with Asus P9D-X board

Tags: memory

I need help on this:

I have an Asus P9D-X board, can I use PC3L-12800U memory modules?

Board Spec Submit Link:

https://www.asus.com/commercial-servers-workstations/p9dx/specifications/

Comment: The memory you have  appears to be non-ECC. The mobo spec states only ECC memory. Unless the data sheet is wrong or incomplete, it won’t work.